# QML: setProperty has no effect

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

When I try to change a property value of an item contained into a ListModel the following code has no effect:

Main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    anchors.fill: parent

    ListModel { id: modelCrayon }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            modelCrayon.append( { _tag: i, _source: "resources/crayon-green.png", _selected: false } )
    }

    Column {
        x: -170
        spacing: 0
        Repeater {
            model: modelCrayon
            delegate: Crayon {
                tag: _tag
                source: _source
                selected: _selected
                onCrayonSelected: {
                    for (var i = 0; i < modelCrayon.count; i++) {
                        if (i == tag) continue;
                        modelCrayon.setProperty(i, "_selected", false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Crayon.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Image {
    property bool selected
    property int tag
    signal crayonSelected()

    id: crayon
    smooth: true
    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit

    onSelectedChanged: console.debug(tag, selected)

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            selected = !selected
            if (selected) crayonSelected()
        }
    }

    states: State {
        name: "selected"; when: selected == true
        PropertyChanges { target: crayon; x: 30 }
    }

    transitions: Transition {
        from: ""; to: "selected"
        PropertyAnimation { property: "x"; duration: 500; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
    }

}
```

Nothing is shown on console, so the "selected" var is never changed.
I'm sure there's something obvious I'm missing.

By the way, is there a smarter way to use a ListModel as a OptionBox? I mean I want only ONE item at time must have the selected property == true. Or, in other words, keep tracks of the selected index.

Comment: I don't know if this is a "real" answer. I would say it's a workaround, but I solved my problem changing the Column in a ListView and setting the selected property as ListView.isCurrentItem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working code to achieve what I asked. But it doens't answer why the property was not set.

```
ListView {
        id: list
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        height: parent.height
        x: -150
        spacing: 0
        orientation: ListView.Vertical
        focus: true
        model: modelCrayon
        delegate: Crayon {
            id: delegate
            source: _source
            selected: ListView.isCurrentItem

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: list.currentIndex = index
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your sample code (the Column version), and it works well with Qt 5.4 / Windows 7 64bit.

What is your running environment?

Comment: Qt 5.5 on RPi2 with a custom Linux buildroot environment